# Creating a simple HTTP proxy in C

Tags: c, http, sockets, tcp, proxy

I'm a newbie programmer looking to create a simple proxy in C that forwards HTTP requests (through TCP). Are there any resources online that can get me started? I've already looked at "Beej's Guide to Network Programming" as it came highly recommended, but I find it to be a little incomplete and hard to follow. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=C+http+proxy

Comment: Do you know how to deal with sockets in C ? If you do, that should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I have very little knowledge of how sockets are programmed in C. Any advice/sources?

Comment: Very smart Karoly Hovath. We get in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

Why reinventing the wheel?
There is tinyproxy that is fully featured, opensource and free.

https://banu.com/tinyproxy/

Comment: Uhhh... 'cuz I want to learn how it all works?

Comment: it seems a good reason, btw Why not starting reading the code?